# Expressing erfi using "regular" functions (ODE)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I've been given a linear first order differential equation which can be written as $ x'(t)+p(t)  x(t)= q(t)$. The general solution formula given is: $x(t)={e^{-P(t)}} \int {e^{P(t)}} \cdot q(t) dt + C {e^{-P(t)}}$ where C is our constant. Specifically, I've been given the DE $ x'(t)+2tx(t)=2t^2 $ and I've been asked if it is possible to use the general solution formula (stated above) to find a solution to the DE which only contains "regular/ordinary" functions. I know I get an erfi function, but the point of the question is to ask if it is possible to write the solution in a different way. Is this possible? If it is, how would I go about it?

So far I've tried to figure out if I might be able to use the derivative of the erfi solution to express the solution using regular functions.

Comment: What are "regular/ordinary" functions? Do you mean elementary functions?

Comment: May be, look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html for series expansions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid special functions, series expansion could be the only way.

Consider the equation
$$x'+2t x=2t^2$$ and use $$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$$ This would give
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_n t^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^{n+1}=2t^2$$ Comparing powers, this would give $a_1=0$ and $a_2=-a_0$. Now, for a degree $m > 2$
$$(m+1)\,a_{m+1}\,t^m+2\,a_{m-1}\,t^m=0\implies a_{m+1}=-\frac{2\, a_{m-1} }{m+1 }$$

Comment: Now I think maybe the OP is asked to derive the series directly from the integral